# Sharepoint form-check for spam words and prevent submission

Tags: sharepoint, forms, block, spam

Looking for:

If 'these words' are entered in this text box

Disable the submit button

Otherwise, submit.

This works for empty required fields:

```
<xsl:if test="@Required='TRUE'">
           <span style="color:#FF0000;font-size:14px;">&#160;*</span>
         </xsl:if>
```

But can't seem to make it work to test for unwanted words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the above code is for displaying * in red color not for disabling the submit button. in case you need to disable the submit button you have to attach javascript to do the same

Comment: Ashutosh, I posted that to show the if test is working to validate the required fields but when I add javascript to detect certain words in a field, it doesn't. So I'm looking for a script that will.

Comment: I ended up using a calculated field which detects "bad" words and throws an alert that has to be closed. Doesn't stop bots submitting the form unfortunately.1/FIND BAD WORDS: =IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"bad","words"}
2/IN THIS COL:  ,p3)),
3/IF THERE, RETURN THIS: alert "Sorry,blah blah"
4/IF NOT, THIS:  ,Pre&p2&Post)